# Emacs GUI only works when launched from the terminal

Tags: emacs

I am using ubuntu 20.04, and I have installed GNU Emacs 27.1 from snap using the command:

```
sudo snap install emacs --classic
```

I want to use it for Python development, but if I launch emacs from the app menu, most of the associated packages don't work (I.e. eldoc, elpy). When I open the terminal and type emacs to access the GUI, everything works fine.

Any tips on how I could troubleshoot this?

Comment: At a guess, your shell is setting up an environment that some parts of your Emacs config are dependent on, and your "app menu" launcher almost certainly isn't going via your shell.

Comment: You must be right. Is there a way for me to configure things so that when I use emacs as my default application for certain files it launches the GUI through the shell?

Comment: You could try modifying the GUI launcher command to run something like `/bin/sh -l -c "emacs"` instead of just `emacs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by uninstalling the snap and installing emacs using the PPA repository.

Comment: Please accept your own answer as correct for future reference.